# How to edit message in pycord without editing the select menu of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, pycord

im currenty creating a discord bot in python using pycord. I have a command that send a message with an embed with two fields. One named Yes and has the value 0 and the other named No also with the value 0. In the select menu I created two options. Option Yes and Option No. My goal is to increase the value of the fields of the embed without resending the select menu, so the selection of it stays in there. My Problem is that I am creating a new Embed with the new value, but when sending the view resets itself.

This is my select menu callback function:

```py
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):

        embed = interaction.message.embeds[0]
        fields = embed.fields

        new_embed = discord.Embed(
            title=embed.title,
            description=embed.description,
        )

        for field in fields:
            if field.name == "Yes" and select.values[0] == "Yes":
                new_embed.add_field(name="Yes", value=str(int(field.value) + 1), inline=True)
                await interaction.response.send_message("You voted for `Yes`", ephemeral=True)
            elif field.name == "No" and select.values[0] == "No":
                new_embed.add_field(name="No", value=str(int(field.value) + 1), inline=True)
                await interaction.response.send_message("ou voted for `No`", ephemeral=True)
            else:
                new_embed.add_field(name=field.name, value=field.value, inline=field.inline)
        await interaction.message.edit(embed=new_embed)
```

I've asked ChatGPT for some solutions, but none of them worked. I also googled and didn't find a solution. I also tried myself and I tried splitting the view and the embed in two messages. Unfortunately without any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this isn't possible because the select menu reset itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can set default-values in your options-list by changing the 'default' parameter on your entries:

```
 async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):

    select.options[0].default = True
    await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
```